# Rational numbers trace

Tags: evaluation

When I [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html) a rational number, I get this quite complicated output:

```
1/2 // Trace
```

> {{1/2,1/2},1/2,1/2}

which under the hood looks like

> {{HoldForm[1/2], HoldForm[1/2]}, HoldForm[1/2], HoldForm[1/2]}

At the same time, `1/2` is represented as [`Rational`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rational.html):

```
1/2 // FullForm
```

> Rational[1, 2]

But if we do:

```
Rational[1, 2] // Trace
```

we get very simple output, which would be expected:

> {Rational[1,2],1/2}

with underlying output being

> {HoldForm[Rational[1, 2]], HoldForm[1/2]}

So, the question is: why MMA does so many steps when evaluating a rational number entered in a "pure" form and doesn't do it when [`Rational`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rational.html) is used explicitly?

Comment: Have you looked at `Trace[1/2] // FullForm` already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `FullForm` should help illuminate things:

```
Hold[1/2]//FullForm
```

> Hold[Times[1,Power[2,-1]]]

We see that 1/2 is a bit more complicated than you might have expected. To evaluate this, you need to first evaluate `Power[2, -1]`, and then you need to multiply that output with 1. So, let's see what happens in the `Trace`:

```
1/2//Trace
% /. h_HoldForm -> FullForm[h]
```

> {{1/2,1/2},1/2,1/2}
>
> {{HoldForm[Power[2,-1]],HoldForm[Rational[1,2]]},HoldForm[Times[1,Rational[1,2]]],HoldForm[Rational[1,2]]}

The `Trace` shows that the evaluation proceeded exactly as expected based on the `FullForm` of the input.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. What doesn't though, is why 1/2 needs to be presented in such a weird way. Any ideas why?

Comment: Probably should make that a different question, a complete answer doesn't really work in a comment. The basic answer is to look at the cell expression corresponding to the input 1/2 (or more generally x/y) using Cell | ShowExpression, and think about how one would convert that cell to an expression.

Comment: Thank you again. Will look into it and possibly post a question.